# Why does jQuery .show not work? (jQuery 2.0.2)

Tags: jquery

I have just started to work jQuery and I can not get this to work. I would like the `appMainNavigationContainer` to appear when I click on the `appBarStartButton` element.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hpD5s/

Html:

```
<div id="appBar" style="border:1px solid blue;">
    <div id="appBarStartButton" style="border:1px solid blue;">WCM v5</div>
    <div id="appBarCaption">@ViewData("Title")</div>
</div>
<div id="appMainNavigationContainer" style="display:none;border:1px solid red;height:100px;">hasdahsdahds
</div>
```

Js:

```
    $("#appBarStartButton").click(function () {
        alert('ha');
        $("appMainNavigationContainer").show('slow');
    });
```

Comment: #appMainNavigationContainer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `#` in the [id selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

```
$("#appMainNavigationContainer").show('slow');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pguFw/)

Comment: save `$("appMainNavigationContainer")` in a variable and log it to the console. You would see that the set is empty. Trying some debugging first might save you from embarrassment in the future;)

Comment: True, although in my defense I did state I was newbie with jQuery. I had no idea what the result is when you do $("appMainNavigationContainer").

Comment: @dcarapic when you say `$("appMainNavigationContainer")`, it works as an [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/), where it looks for elements with tag name `appMainNavigationContainer`. Probably before starting to work with jQuery you need to go through the [selector documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)